ros2 communications between two identical RPI
I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with ROS2 humble on each of two Raspberry pi 4B with 4GB. I have a publisher package and a subscriber package. When I run the publisher and subscriber nodes in separate terminals on either of the two RPi's, everything works as expected and the two nodes send and receive data successfully. However, when I run the publisher node on one RPi and the subscriber node on the second RPi, no communication occurs. Both devices can ping each other. 'IP addr' returns similar info for both devices, and indicates multicasting is allowed. 'ros2 node list' and 'ros2 topic list' both return correct information. I am not setting DOMIAN_IDs so both devices should be defaulting to 0. I can't find much information on two ROS2 RPi devices communicating with each other. Seems like this should work but I'm not having success.  Have other folks successfully communicated between separate RPi devices using ROS2? I'm a bit of a newbie with ROS2, so I apologize if I am missing something obvious. Any helpful suggestions would be truly appreciated.

FWIW, I think that there was a similar question asked a few days (weeks?) ago, about intercommunication (using an RPi). I don't have time to try and find it though, unfortunately.

Thanks. I think I found the reference. Looks like I might have to mess with DDS.

Ah good, glad you found it. I still haven't had time to look. Do you have the link?
